# Initialization on a static class?

Tags: java, static

If I have a helper class with static methods, how can I do some initialization best?

```
public class MyClass {

   //init a properties file
   {
     properties.load(..)
   }

   public static String getStringFromProperty(String name);
       return properties.getProperty(name);
   }
}
```

Is there a better way for initialization than a static code block?

Comment: You should probably have a `static` in front of that block

Comment: In a static block would be a preferable way I guess. And you do that if you have static variables, not the methods.

Comment: It must be in static block. Otherwise, the property will not be loaded unless an instance of MyClass class is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this...

`static initializer block` to **initialize the property** when the class is loaded.

```
public class MyClass {


  static
        {
          properties.load(..)
        }

   public static String getStringFromProperty(String name);

       return properties.getProperty(name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which allows you to design your class as a regular normal class. In this case you would do the initialization in the constructor. If your running under an application server you could also [EJBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) to provide your static services (e.g DAOs).

Answer (score 0):

> First thing to know; this function can only call static methods and
>   properties of the class.

So better declare property as static.

public static String getStringFromProperty(String name);
       return properties.getProperty(name);
   }